# have_selector parameters having no effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, css-selectors, capybara, rspec2

I am working on an RSpec test and am trying to make use of the have_selector method but it does not seem to be working as anticipated and the tests seem to pass regardless of what id i put in. I have tried with 'organisation' and 'organizations' which both pass regardless of the fact that it should only pass for :id => 'minibar-organisations'

```
it "minibar should have uniquely named Organisations link" do
  visit 'http://localhost:3000/'
  minibar = find(:xpath, '//*[@id="minibar"]')  
  minibar.should have_selector('li', :id => 'minibar-organisation')       
end
```

How can I effectively use this method so only those **li** that have this id will be recognised.

Comment: anyone know where I am going wrong on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `have_selector` actually takes an 'id' option.  You can specify the expected ID as part of the selector instead:

```
minibar.should have_selector('li#minibar-organisation')
```

Comment: Thanks John I was unaware of the #for ID and .for Class so this is most useful :)

Comment: No problem, perhaps you could mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem!  Cheers